# PhpStorm very slow even though I gave 4GB ram to custom VM

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have

> PhpStorm 2018.1.6
>   Build #PS-181.5281.35, built on June 15, 2018
>   macOS 10.13.5

on my brandnew 2017 Macbook Pro, with 16gb ram.

At first, it is fast, but at some point, it gets slow. Just as slow as the dragging itself lags, typing is impossible because the text is so slowly responses, etc.

It is a nightmare.

I've done everything I can do at this moment. My `Custom VM Options` Here :

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_phpstorm_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_phpstorm.hprof

-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dawt.java2d.opengl=true
```

Comment: Whenever you start phpstorm, your project files get indexed (it took a little bit more time to index Ur whole project files) Once indexing finished, u will find it smooth functioning.

Comment: Are the project files located on a local disk or on a remote share?
Are there any 3rd-party plugins? If so then did you try to disable them?

Comment: You can also check [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000693290-Extreme-lag-and-high-CPU-usage-on-OSX-High-Sierra) and see what helped to other people (something helps to one person; something to another; often it has to do with graphic driver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that same issue on my MacBook Pro too. I didn't find any solutions and I was frustrated.

First, please open a blank project without any modules / compilers and start play with it. If the IDE doesn't freeze, then it has to do something with your project, or some plug-in that gets triggered in your project.

I found out that phpStorm saved my project each time I typed something without moving to another app (haven't figured out why. I moved to another machine so I can't reproduce that problem) which caused a massive resources. Try to disable the auto save.

Make sure you exclude the directories you don't need to index (e.g node_modules, dist). Your IDE shouldn't index them.

Disable all of the plugins you're using. They're mostly the source of all performance problems.

Comment: *all of the plugins you're *not* using :) There are also Java issues like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-526 that yet to be fixed.

Comment: @Vlad let's settle on *all* plugins :D